# Is Visual Studio for mac working well with Unity (IDE) on mac?

Tags: ios, macos, unity-game-engine

I am very new to Unity, I am wondering if the newly release Visual Studio for mac works well with Unity IDE on mac? Regarding of debugging, etc.

I am currently using MonoDevelop for the debugging.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try it by yourself and make your own opinion? ;)

Comment: @Hellium, to save time obviously.

Answer (score 2):

It works well, yes. Pretty stable as well.

The only drawback for me is that it is still extremely limited, not that much better than MonoDevelop really. Many features/behaviours are different from its Windows counterpart.

For me worth checking out but still at an early stage...

Answer (score 0):

I recently moved to Mac, and tried using VS Community. After few hours I decided to try VS Code just to check it.

I decided to stay with VSCode, but i also installed all needed extensions in it, and also https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/45320 to unity.

That configuration suits me quite nice. I found it nearly as good as VS on Windows

Comment: Thanks. VS Code is different from Visual Studio for Mac, these are two things. Check out the newly released Visual Studio for Mac. :)